# Username already exists, when want to update userprofile in django

Tags: django

Whenever I try try to update a userprofile on django powered web, I get the error: "username already exists, please provide another one." I am trying to get it to recognize the authenticated user. Although every other thing works, it will not update until I specify a new username.

views.py

```
@login_required
def editprofile(request):
    registeredmember = request.user.get_profile()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userprofile_edit = RegistrationForm(request.POST, instance = registeredmember)
        if userprofile_edit.is_valid():
            userprofile_edit.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        userprofile_edit = RegistrationForm(instance = registeredmember)
    return render_to_response('carloan/editprofile.html', {'userprofile_edit': userprofile_edit}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the username field when you are Editing the profile.

Something like this in your `RegistrationForm`.

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.form):
   #other code

   class Meta:
       exclude = ['username',]
```

You can add multiple field names which you don't want to be included in the form